# Inconsistency of arity between Hash.each and lambdas

Tags: ruby, lambda, closures, proc-object

I lifted the following example from [Josh Susser](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/6/20/recursive-lambda)

```
  def strip_accents params
    thunk = lambda do |key,value|
      case value
        when String then value.remove_accents!
        when Hash   then value.each(&thunk)
      end
    end
    params.each(&thunk)
  end
```

when I put it in the the rails console (irb), and call it with a hash, I get the following:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :044 > `ruby --version`
 => "ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux]\n"
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :045 > strip_accents({:packs=>{:qty=>1}})
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
        from (irb):32:in `block in strip_accents'
        from (irb):37:in `each'
        from (irb):37:in `strip_accents'
        from (irb):45
        from /longpathtrimedforclarity/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /longpathtrimedforclarity/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /longpathtrimedforclarity/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I understand that lambdas check arity, but I see two arguments in the lambda definition.  If I change `lambda do` to `Proc.new do`, The code executes, and I get the expected result.

Josh's example is from 2008, so I'm assuming this is a difference in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it appears to have changed between 1.8 and 1.9, but this change fixes it for 1.9.2, at least in my tests:

```
def strip_accents params
  thunk = lambda do |h|
    key, value = h
    case value
    when String then value.remove_accents!
    when Hash   then value.each(&thunk)
    end
  end
  params.each(&thunk)
end
```

This approach turns out to be backward-compatible with Ruby 1.8.7, as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash#each`, just like every other `#each` method, yields *one* argument to the block. In the case of `Hash#each`, that one argument is a two-element array consisting of the key and the value.

So, `Hash#each` yields *one* argument, but your lambda has *two* mandatory parameters, therefore you get an arity error.

It works with blocks, since blocks are less strict about their arguments, and in particular, if a block has multiple parameters, but only gets one argument, it will try to deconstruct the argument as if it had been passed in with a splat.

There are two kinds of `Proc`s: lambdas and non-lambdas (confusingly, the latter are usually also called `Proc`s). Lambdas behave like methods in terms of how the `return` keyword behaves and (more importantly, for this case) how they bind arguments, whereas non-lambda `Proc`s behave like blocks in terms of how `return` and argument binding work. That's why `Proc.new` (which creates a non-lambda `Proc`) works, but `lambda` (which obviously creates a lambda) doesn't.

You can check whether a `Proc` is a lambda or not by calling `Proc#lambda?`.

If you want to deconstruct the argument, you will have to do so explicitly, the same way you would when you define a method:

```
lambda do |(key, value)|
```

And, yes, a more sane approach to argument binding for blocks, `Proc`s and lambdas *was* one of the major backwards-incompatible changes in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: FWIW, the Pickaxe used the term "raw proc" to distinguish between the proc style proc and the lambda style proc. I don't think this is exactly textbook Liskov Substitution Principle behavior, though.