# How can I splattify an anonymous object so I can use &method on it?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, splat, arity

I'm wanting to use the `&method(:method_name)` idiom when there's more than one object required by `method_name`. Can I do this under Ruby 1.9?

For example, if I've got

```
def move_file(old_filename, new_filename)
  STDERR.puts "Moving #{old_filename.inspect} to #{new_filename.inspect}"
  # Implementation for careful moving goes here
end

old_filenames = ["foo.txt", "bar.txt", "hoge.ja.txt"]
new_filenames = ["foo_20110915.txt", "bar_20110915.txt", "hoge_20110915.ja.txt"]
```

the code

```
old_filenames.zip(new_filenames).each(&method(:move_file))
```

works under Ruby 1.8, but not under Ruby 1.9. Under Ruby 1.9, it's trying to do `move_file(["foo.txt", "foo_20110915.txt"])` instead of `move_file("foo.txt", "foo_20110915.txt")`.

How do I splattify it so it has the correct arity?

Workarounds I'm aware of:

1. Replace `def move_file(old_filename, new_filename)` with `def move_file(*arguments)`
2. Replace `each(&method(:move_file))` with
   `each{|old_filename, new_filename| move_file(old_filename, new_filename)}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
each{|old_filename, new_filename| move_file(old_filename, new_filename)}
```

you should be able to do

```
each{|pair| move_file(*pair)}
```

But I don't know how you'd pull off blockless variant (I needed it couple of times as well). I guess &-shorthand was made to make the syntax simpler, and is not meant to be clogged much (whether it will be passed an array as an array, or splatted, for example). :)

Comment: What did you mean by "clogged"?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native... I meant that you somehow need to pass the information whether you want your array to be splatted or not - i.e. use some additional syntax around your `&method(:name)` argument. At one point once concise `&`-style could become bulky and unreadable so that its benefit become questionable.

Answer (score 0):

> > How do I splattify it so it has the correct arity?

I don't think there is a way to do this while being compatible to both Ruby versions. What you could do is wrap it into a lambda

move_from_to = Proc.new {|*both| move_files(*both) }

The thing is - block and proc arity is something that got addressed in Ruby 1.9 so there might be a difference in behavior there. Also see `prc.lambda?` here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html for info on what it does to the arity.

This question is also related to what you want to do (the solution there is to resplat and unsplat manually): [Inconsistency of arity between Hash.each and lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262738/hash-each-with-lambda-arity-problem)