# How do I pass a lambda to Hash.each?

Tags: ruby, lambda

How can I pass a lambda to `hash.each`, so I can re-use some code?

```
> h = { a: 'b' }
> h.each do |key, value| end
 => {:a=>"b"}
> test = lambda do |key, value| puts "#{key} = #{value}" end 
> test.call('a','b')
a = b
> h.each &test
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
  from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
  from (irb):5:in `each'
  from (irb):5
  from /Users/jstillwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
> h.each test
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
  from (irb):8:in `each'
  from (irb):8
  from /Users/jstillwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the question clean-up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`each` yields the current element to the block, ergo the lambda needs to take one argument, not two. In case of a `Hash` the element being yielded is a two-element `Array` with the first element being the key and the second element being the value.

```
test = lambda do |el| puts "#{el.first} = #{el.last}" end
h.each &test
# a = b
```

Alternatively, you can use Ruby's support for destructuring bind in parameter lists:

```
test = lambda do |(k, v)| puts "#{k} = #{v}" end
h.each &test
# a = b
```

Or, instead of using a `lambda` which has the same argument binding semantics as a method, you could use a `Proc`, which has the same argument binding semantics as a block, i.e. it will unpack a single `Array` argument into multiple parameter bindings:

```
test = proc do |k, v| puts "#{k} = #{v}" end
h.each &test
# a = b
```

Comment: The issue I have (after I found the answer) is that, as you can see on my second line of code, `each` clearly takes a block with 2 arguments. It just fails to take a `lambda` with 2 arguments. WTF

Comment: `each` *always* yields a *single* argument. *Always*. No exceptions. If you pass a *single* `Array` to a block which takes *multiple* parameters, then the `Array` will be unpacked into the parameters similarly to parallel assignment. But that doesn't have anything to do with `each`, that's just basic Ruby 101 parameter passing.

Comment: There's the magic. yield/block unpacks a **single Array** if possible. I couldn't find this documented anywhere, and didn't suspect it. Thanks Jörg.

Comment: Yes, and `Proc`s have the same parameter passing semantics as blocks (lenient arity checking, array unpacking), whereas `lambda`s have the same parameter passing semantics as methods (strict arity checking, no unpacking).

Answer (score 1):

I still feel this is inconsistent syntax, I found the answer (but no apology) in another question
[Inconsistency of arity between Hash.each and lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262738/inconsistency-of-arity-between-hash-each-and-lambdas)

I switched it to

```
lambda do |(key, value)|
```

then I can pass in

```
hash.each &test
```

or I can call it directly with

```
test.call([key, value])
```

If someone has a better answer, or at least a succinct excuse why this is necessary. I'll gladly give them the points.

Comment: You needed this transformation because `h.each` was passing each pair as a single object, an array. The array was passed to your `key` param and you were missing one for `value`. With the `(key, value)` notation, it passes the array's value correctly to each of them. Like when you write `a, b = [1, 2]`

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel that you need an "excuse" here. `each` *always* yields a *single* argument. Your lambda takes *two* arguments. Obviously, that cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a similar case where I wanted not to print but to return a key-value pair after doing some operation with the value... the above solution applies when you just want to print but it can become tricky when you need to return a Hash of those key-value pairs. so  I thought this could be helpful

I used it to solve the [caesar-cipher](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/) puzzle

```
hash1 = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
test = lambda {|k,v| true ? {k => v+2} : {k => v+1} }
```

after mapping this to an hash it will return an array of Hashes (here is where things get interesting)

```
hash2 = hash1.map(&test)   # [{"a"=>3}, {"b"=>4}, {"c"=>5}]
```

we can convert it to hash rubystically!

```
hash2.inject(:merge!)   # {"a" => 3, "b" => 4, "c" => 5}
```

Bingo!!! right?